# Filtering out consecutive rows from dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the index values and one datetime variable as follows:

```
1      2017-01-03 09:30:01.958
46     2017-01-03 09:30:47.879
99     2017-01-03 09:33:48.121
117    2017-01-03 09:47:06.215
139    2017-01-03 09:51:06.054
1567   2017-01-03 14:17:18.949
2480   2017-01-03 15:57:13.442
2481   2017-01-03 15:57:14.333
2486   2017-01-03 15:57:37.500
2487   2017-01-03 15:57:38.677
2489   2017-01-03 15:57:41.053
2491   2017-01-03 15:57:54.870
2498   2017-01-03 15:59:24.210
```

What I am trying to do is to remove consecutive rows from the data (only retaining the first observation from the segment), in this case the code should drop the rows with index 2481 and 2487. I tried using

```
df[df.index.diff() == 0].drop()
```

but it only returned

```
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for working with `index` with not implemented method use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df = df[df.index.to_series().diff() != 1]
print (df)
                         date
1     2017-01-03 09:30:01.958
46    2017-01-03 09:30:47.879
99    2017-01-03 09:33:48.121
117   2017-01-03 09:47:06.215
139   2017-01-03 09:51:06.054
1567  2017-01-03 14:17:18.949
2480  2017-01-03 15:57:13.442
2486  2017-01-03 15:57:37.500
2489  2017-01-03 15:57:41.053
2491  2017-01-03 15:57:54.870
2498  2017-01-03 15:59:24.210
```

Thank you [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429440/filtering-out-consecutive-rows-from-dataset#comment77821981_45430296) for numpy alternative:

```
df[np.append(0, np.diff(df.index.values)) != 1]
```

**Timings**:

```
#[11000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

In [60]: %timeit [True] + [(i[0]+1) != i[1] for i in zip(df.index.tolist(), df.index.tolist()[1:])]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.19 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit np.append(0, np.diff(df.index.values)) != 1
The slowest run took 4.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.1 µs per loop

In [62]: %timeit df.index.to_series().diff() != 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 260 µs per loop
```

Comment: I knew you guys had something in your sleeve. Interestingly the [df.index.to_series().diff() != 1] will return the same thing

Comment: I'm a fan of readability and like your version more, however I did a timecomparison, why is this so much slower? Is it the to_series() conversion?

Comment: Same answer but `numpy-fied` ___  `df[np.append(0, np.diff(df.index.values)) != 1]`  That should quicken it up.

Comment: @AntonvBR - There was problem you test samm dataframe, in larger it is faster.

Comment: Can you add my answer to timing?  Thanks

Comment: what if the actual dataset has more than one column? what should i use in lieu of .to_series()?

Comment: @AdrianY - Do you need `Multiindex` ? More columns in index?

Comment: @jezrael - nope I don't. I think it was some syntax error on my part because it's working now. thanks!

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

more `numpy`

```
df[np.append(True, df.index.values[1:] != df.index.values[:-1] + 1)]

                        date
1    2017-01-03 09:30:01.958
46   2017-01-03 09:30:47.879
99   2017-01-03 09:33:48.121
117  2017-01-03 09:47:06.215
139  2017-01-03 09:51:06.054
1567 2017-01-03 14:17:18.949
2480 2017-01-03 15:57:13.442
2486 2017-01-03 15:57:37.500
2489 2017-01-03 15:57:41.053
2491 2017-01-03 15:57:54.870
2498 2017-01-03 15:59:24.210
```